# JspellCheck Error

Tags: ckeditor

*ERROR: JSpell is already attached, or jspellInit has not been called before calling jspellCheck.* Does anyone Know solution to this?I am getting this when i am integrating with Ckeditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the following two lines of JavaScript code onto every page that needs to use JSpell Evolution. Note, it is standard practice to place these lines in the HEAD section of your HTML document.  You may need to modify the URLs to the JavaScript files depending on your environment (note, these JavaScript files *MUST* be on the same server AND port as your web pages otherwise the spell checker will not work correctly).

```
<script TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="/jspellEvolution/jspellSettings.js" CHARSET="ISO-8859-1"></script> 
<script TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="/jspellEvolution/jspellEvolution.js" CHARSET="ISO-8859-1"></script>
```

http://www.jspell.com/wiki/index.php/JSpell_Evolution#Adding_JSpell_to_Your_Web_Page